# MySQL efficiently add primary key

Tags: mysql, primary-key

Suppose I have a relatively large table in a database, (~10 million records, ~20 GB), is there an efficient / recommended way to add a primary key to this set?

Presuming I have a valid primary key candidate (unique in the data set)
I see two potential candidates for an approach:

1. Run 'ALTER TABLE ... ADD PRIMARY KEY (...);' command
2. Create an empty table with same structure and new primary key; load in batches

I'm sure the answer varies with the size of the table and the configuration of the server; but are there any rules of thumb to be considered?

Comment: Is this database in production? Do you have other constraints?

Comment: Database is in production but this table lies undisturbed with the exception of some large batch updates ran overnight

Comment: I would first make sure the primary key candidate is really unique, with a query `group by *cols* having count(*) > 1` (should return nothing). Then just alter the table to add the primary key in the morning so it can finish before the night batches.

Comment: @Guillaume F. - you can also use **INSERT IGNORE INTO new_Table SELECT * FROM old_table ORDER BY some_field**. Then the new_table is ordert . To change the both table you can use the atomic function RENAME like **RENAME org_table to org_table_old, new_table to org_table;**

Comment: One thing to be aware of for your second option if there are any foreign keys referencing this table, when you swing the old table out and the new one in, the foreign keys will still point to the old table.